# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Tags: installation

Attempting to install Drupal 7.16 (also attempted 7.12) onto my local machine, I get the following error at the database stage.

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Looking at the Drupal database with PHPMyAdmin, I see the "variables" table is created, together two columns; that is all that gets created prior to the error.

I can't find a single solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due to the index limitations. From the MySQL docs: [`CREATE INDEX` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html)

> Prefix support and lengths of prefixes (where supported) are storage engine dependent. For example, a prefix can be up to 1000 bytes long for `MyISAM` tables, and **767 bytes for `InnoDB` tables.**

You probably have a `VARCHAR` column with length more than 767 or a `TEXT` column.

Comment: Yes I did. But I've finally solved it - I found the script used to create the tables, and chaged the engine to MyISAM - thanks to your suggestion. Really appreciate your help!